# Error with Pre-installed Postgresql for Mac OSX 10.7 "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-lion, postgis

Need help fixing my postgresql, the pre-installed one that comes with OSX Lion.

I get the error

```
psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

also, when i use the terminal command "which psql" I get

```
/usr/bin/psql
```

So it seems as if I'm pointing at the right psql installation. Also, I've recently finished removing all previous installations of postgres/postgres apps, etc, and I've also removed anything relating to those previous versions of postgres from my ".bash_profile".

As an added piece of information, I tried to use the Postgres.app and continue to get Version 9.2.4.3 and I receive and "Unexpected quit message", I think this may be part of the same problem.

Error message when quitting:

```
Process:         com.heroku.postgres-service [49859]
```

Path:            /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/XPCServices/com.heroku.postgres-service.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.heroku.postgres-service
Identifier:      com.heroku.postgres-service
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  com.heroku.postgres-service [49856]

Date/Time:       2013-09-05 12:55:08.176 -0400
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  9

Anonymous UUID:                      7F2C7D7B-4EF2-4ED5-A570-94393FBE5F97

Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007fff5fc01028

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000055  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000000000000
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff5fc01028  rfl: 0x0000000000010203  cr2: 0x00007fff5fc01028
Logical CPU: 0

Binary images description not available

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 3164
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

Model: MacBookPro8,1, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 10 GB, SMC 1.68f99
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341384758334D314131333333433920
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.198.19.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 11 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK5065GSXF, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 3
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfa100000 / 2
USB Device: USB Receiver, 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.), 0xc51b, 0xfa130000 / 6
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 5
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 8
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0252, 0xfa120000 / 4
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3

Comment: PostgreSQL ships with OS X Server Edition only. `/usr/bin/psql` does not mean that you have the postgresql server, it's just a client-side program. See http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/ and reinstall a server, either from `postgres.app` or another source.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with host option:

```
psql -h localhost
```

You can add this line to your `.bash_profile` file:

```
export PGHOST=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Permission denied suggests a file permission issue.  Make sure that the socket file exists where it is supposed to be, and that you can list /var/ and /var/pgsql_socket/

If that doesn't fix it, install PostgreSQL via Homebrew.